# Should Case-Shiller be graphed logarithmically?

Tags: case-shiller-index

As the increase in value of equities, inflation indexes, and a raw “average” home price all typically grow exponentially as opposed to linearly, I would venture that graphing these prices over time is more appropriate on an exponential scale. Given the structure of the Case-Shiller index, does it make more sense to also graph it logarithmically, or has some part of its calculation already taken this into account?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The index is designed as a proportional measure of home prices, so plotting it on a log scale is useful for the same reasons as for other price measures, i.e., to make equal *percentage* changes equally prominent and to show changes over a wide range of magnitudes. It may matter less in this case because home prices are not very volatile and the typical history being plotted is not very long.